# How do I pass multiple class attributes through django to the template?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

Getting this error:
Exception Value:
Could not parse the remainder: ' + contact.last_name' from 'contact.first_name + contact.last_name'

I am having trouble displaying a list of names, with each name as a link.

My models.py code:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

My views.py code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pk.models import Contact
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    contact_list = Contact.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('pk/index.html', {'contact_list': contact_list})
```

My index.html template:

```
{% if contact_list %}
<ul>
{% for contact in contact_list %}
    <li><a href="/pkl/{{ contact.id }}/">{{ contact.first_name + contact.last_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No contacts are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
{{ contact.first_name }} {{ contact.last_name }}
```

Django doesn't know what to do with the `+`, and you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

for a not so long contact list , 
eg:

```
def index(request):
contact_list = Contact.objects.all()
for  i in contact_list:
      contactlist.append(i.first_name + i.last_name)
return render_to_response('pk/index.html', {'contact_list': contactlist})
```

Comment: python list is not efficiency like say set or tuple etc